# How to disable highlight color when clicking to a cell in Caldroid Calendar?

Tags: android, calendar, caldroid

I want to disable highlight color (orange in the picture attached).

How to do it?

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Which calendar u have used default or any third party ?

Comment: Ah, I used a third party. https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

Comment: It's already explain there to change the background color . U have try that

Comment: Ah, I can change the background color. But I can't change the highlight color when I am selecting a cell. Just tap, tap tap! And it will change from white -> orange -> white...

Comment: <item name="styleCaldroidNormalCell">@style/CaldroidDefaultDarkNormalCell</item>
        <item name="styleCaldroidSquareCell">@style/CaldroidDefaultDarkSquareCell</item>

Comment: try to edit these both colors

Comment: hmm.. let me try... thank a lot,  Nithinlal and quick learner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Delete the (orange)xml inside drawable and then your highlight will gone